# NegotiateStream rejecting clients that aren't local admins

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have a very basic client/server test set up that fails with the message:

> The server has rejected the client credentials.

Unless the client is logged on as an account that has admin rights on the server.  This is something I do not want.

Here is my client code:

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

...

using (var client = new TcpClient(ip, 1248))
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
using (var negStream = new NegotiateStream(stream, false))
{
    await negStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, string.Empty, ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign, TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification));
    formatter.Serialize(negStream, "This is a test!");
}
```

And here is my server code:

```
var listener = new TcpListener.Create(1248);
listener.Start();

var tcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
using (var stream = tcpClient.GetStream())
using (var negStream = new NegotiateStream(stream, false))
{
    await negStream.AuthenticateAsServerAsync(CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign, TokenImpersonationLevel.Identification));
    Console.WriteLine(formatter.Deserialize(negStream));
}
```

How do I configure the server to accept any logged on user?  Is there another setting I need to look at? Is there another way to authenticate a stream with domain credentials?

Comment: Have you checked the security event log on the server? Which OS version are you running?

Comment: The Security event log has no failures.  Nothing looks out of the ordinary.  I'm running on Server 2012 R2 and Windows 7.

Comment: Under what account is the server and client running? (Domain-Accounts, NetworkService, LocalUser)  And try to use the simple overloads off  AuthenticateAsServer() and AuthenticateAsClient()

Comment: The `TcpClient` is running as a domain service account on the webserver, and the `TcpListener` is running as normal user.  If I change out the service account for an admin account, everything works.

Comment: Please describe which user is which in that form: **WORKS** TcpClient - domain user, admin on `TcpClient`, admin on `TcpListener`. `TcpListener` - domain user, normal on `TcpClient`, normal on `TcpListener`. And same for **FAILS**

Answer (score 1):

This May sound crazy, but you can give it a try, ,it worked for me anyway

open folder-> view tab -> options -> view tab -> scroll down and uncheck "use sharing wizard"

Comment: As far as I know this answer worth a try.

Comment: The bounty will be over before I get to try, so better give it before it's too late!  Here's for hoping!

Comment: thank you :), hope it works... please let me know if it dosen't